# TextBox not updating on property change

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm new to WinForms and C# in general, however the issue I'm having is so basic it even astounds me.  What I have is a small UserControl that contains 3 text boxes so that a vector in 3-D space can be displayed.  The control has a property which allows the consumer to set the Vector being displayed by the control.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Read/Write property to set the displayed vector.
    /// </summary>
    public Vector3 Vector
    {
        get { return m_vector; }
        set
        {
            m_vector = value;
            string val = Convert.ToString(m_vector.X);
            txtX.Text = val;
            txtY.Text = Convert.ToString(m_vector.Y);
            txtZ.Text = Convert.ToString(m_vector.Z);
        }
    }
```

You'll notice that I split out the conversion from the actual assigning of the text property for debugging purposes.  In any case, val contains exactly what it should.  Inspecting txtX in the debugger shows that it was set properly.  However, the value never updates on screen.

Very little is done to initialize the TextBox other than setting position, size, and name.  This was all done in the Visual Studio designer.  Can anyone point out what I might be doing wrong?

EDIT:  Adding the calling code.

```
public override void LeftDrag(float deltaX, float deltaY)
    {
        float length = 2 * (Eye - Center).Length * (float)Math.Tan(FOVy / 2.0);

        Vector3 lookAt = Center - Eye;
        Vector3 dirY = Vector3.Cross(Up, lookAt);
        dirY.Normalize();

        Center += deltaY * length * Up;
        Center += deltaX * length * Width / Height * dirY;
    }
```

Comment: From your code there is nothing wrong. Are you sure that your textbox isn't updated elsewhere?

Comment: No, the only way to update the Text property is through this property I've shown.  I just set a breakpoint to make sure no bad input was going through and it doesn't seem that it is.

Comment: Probably something in the calling code prevents the update. Could you show the calling method?

Comment: In fact, I just trapped the TextChanged event and output the value of the Text property.... everything is sane.  For some reason the TextBox won't update visually though.

Comment: Just being the not so awesome responder here but does the textbox have a white background and a black foreground?

Comment: @Silvermind At this point I'll take anything. :)  Alas, no it just keeps its initial value.

Comment: Your 'calling code' isn't calling the property Vector on any Vector3 vars. Am I in error?

Comment: @Steve Up, Center, Eye, and dirY are all other Vector3's.  This vector class comes from OpenTK and overloads all the appropriate arithmetic operations.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Silvermind I'm not following... the Vector property is mine.  the Vector3 class has members X, Y, and Z which provide access to individual elements of the vector.

Comment: What he means is that nowhere you can see `MyObject.Vector = SelectedVector;`

Comment: What is the classname containing the Vector property?

Comment: if you have confirmed that txtX.Text has the correct value, then the two possibilities that come to mind are 1: that txtX has been set somewhere and is no longer referencing the textbox on your form; or 2: that something is getting in the way of painting the controls.

Comment: I don't know if the OpenTK in its + - operator overloading set the Vector property. However we could find easily. While executing the calling code set a breakpoint on the setter and see if the the debug stop at the breakpoint

Comment: Wow, I think I see it now.  I have no idea how this compiles... but it seems theres some circular logic thats likely a result of some refactoring.  Good eye.  (Now I'm new to StackOverflow... how would I give you guys credit for the solution?)

Comment: @Steve If Steve copies his comment into the Answer box than you can accept the answer. Best regards.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help.... I knew this was going to be something stupid I couldn't see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if the OpenTK in its + - operator overloading set the Vector property. However we could find easily. While executing the calling code set a breakpoint on the setter and see if the the debug stop at the breakpoint. If it's not then you should, somewhere in your calling code, set the Vector property, so the setter will be called.

Something like

```
Vector3 lookAt = Center - Eye;
lookAt.Vector = Center - Eye;
```